# Backbone.js execute function when subview is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a view named DatesView and a subview named DateView. I would like to execute a function in DatesView when an instance of DateView is clicked.

```
var Date = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Dates = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Date
});

var DateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'clicked'
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.text(this.model.get('date'));

        return this;
    }
})

var DatesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        this.collection.each(function (date) {
            var dateView = new DateView({model: date});

            this.$el.append(dateView.render().el)
        }, this);

        return this;
    },

    clicked: function() {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
})

var dates = new Dates([
    {date: '01'},
    {date: '02'},
    {date: '03'}
])

var datesView = new DatesView({collection: dates});

$('#container').html(datesView.render().el);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu46fpwt/2/)

As you  can see in the example the DateView has an event setup for click, which I would like to register in the DatesView. The way it is written now does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite like using Backbone events. You can use it as follows:

Trigger the event in your DateView

```
clicked: function () {
    Backbone.trigger('date:clicked');
}
```

Listen for the event in the DatesView

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'date:clicked', this.clicked);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to accept a "clicked" option in your sub view:

```
var DateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'clicked'
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        // allow parent to pass in a click handler
        this.clicked = options.clicked;
    }
    // snip...
})

var DatesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        this.collection.each(function (date) {
            // pass parentView's click method to child, 
            // binding context to parent
            var dateView = new DateView({
                  model: date, 
                  clicked: this.clicked.bind(this)
            });

            this.$el.append(dateView.render().el)
        }, this);

        return this;
    },
    // snip...
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcqt51nu/1/)